# Site displayed by foreign / unwanted URL

Tags: wordpress, url

I have a website : 
http://bamboo-straws.com

But since yesterday I see that this site is displaying it as well : 
http://kevineger.xyz

The problem is that it totally f**k up my SEO. My site doesn't even show up in the 20 first pages, while if you google the other, it appears in page 4-5, showing my title, description etc.

I tryed to look about solution but I have no idea what to do.

It seems that their DNS is pointing to my IP.

I just did set up a "no hot linking" so they don't have the images anymore...

The site is based on wordpress.

Very unlucky, we launched the product a few days ago...

Comment: If they are simply pointing at your IP and getting the site to display that means your default server-block in your nginx config is set to serve the site to anyone who requests content from that IP. Type the IP into your browser and you'll get the site to display too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informations William Patton.

If I get it right, I should set up "nginx" to whitelist my URL to serve the content and block all others?
Is it possible to do this with a simple HTACCESS ?
Unfortunately I'm really not familiar with web server..

I hope I'm not abusing of stack overflow by asking such request, but if you have any of how to solve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Again, thank you very much.

Fred.

Comment: I checked the headers that your server attaches to pages that get requested and it looks as though your server runs on NGINX (which means no .htaccess file since that's an Apache server thing). I just posted somewhat of an answer that links you to a page at at the NGINX wiki which details what a default server-block is and how it will look in your config file. This is most definitely a server issue so if you're not comfortable playing around with server configs then you should probably reach out to someone who is comfortable making changes like this and have them correct the error.

Comment: Also the reason your question was probably downvoted is how it is worded and the fact that it doesn't include any real technical information (understandable since you're not all that familiar with how the hosting or the server works).

Comment: Thank you again. I understand that I didn't gave enough informations, unfortunately this is beyong my skills. I have the read the link you gave me and found some informations about the nginx configuration. Unfortunately it seems that I can't access the config via FTP and have to do it by SSH, wich i'm absolutely not confortable with. Again, thank you again, I will try to seek some help from someone who knows more than me. As soon as I solve the problem I'll validate your answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem for providing the help I have. This may require someone to access the site via SSH however if you know the root password you can connect via sftp and do it (if you use filezilla then simply set the port to '22' and that will set it to sftp mode). Click my name, reach out to me on Twitter if you can and I may be able to walk you through this in a more in-depth way.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have twitter :/ I connected via sftp with the root access but I didn't see the files supposed to have the configuration : /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /opt/nginx/conf/ All I see when I'm in the root folder is : .cach .config .ssh . .locals app - log - run - tmp - bash_history - bash_logout - bashrc cloud-locale-test.skip - nano_history - .profile. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure serverpilot the right way so its pointing to right app. Or add the domain to an existing app. Its basically pointing to the default app right now, which is in your case bamboo-straws.com.

You can also point the unwanted domain to an "empty" default app. Create a .htaccess file in the app's folder:

`Deny from all`

Btw, you are running an apache server not NGINX.

Comment: I guess that since this is marked as correct answer that this fixed the issue however `curl -I bamboo-straws.com` returns `server: nginx`. How did you determine that the server is apache not NGINX?

Comment: NGINX pipes the stuff of apache through in this case. I only figured out by seeing an error message with a path of the error log file serverpilot uses.

Comment: similar to: `curl 104.131.182.181` which display now the apache log path

Answer (score 2):

The problem here seems to be that you are serving this site as the default content whenever anyone requests something from this IP. You need to change the server-block in your nginx configuration so this site is not the default that is sent.

This page on the nginx wiki shows how that is done https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

As a side note there is a chance that this is actually not malicious. This domain was registered some time ago and points at the Digital Ocean nameservers, they probably had the same IP address you have now at DO attached onto their droplet and once they released it then it got assigned to you. I see this myself in request logs at my Digital Ocean droplets from sites requesting to use my DNS and bots trying to access the site - I just simply don't serve them any content as I chose not to have a default server-block.